# Redirect outbound traffic to a different port

Tags: routes, network-programming, port, firewall, iptables

I have legacy windows machine with even more lagacy software. From time to time, some of the programs sends an email through 1.2.3.4 smtp server using port 25. The problem is, that ISP blocked port 25 and they said to me that I have to change software to send email through port 587.

Is it possible to do without changing the software? I was thinking about redirecting all traffic that goes to 1.2.3.4:25 to 1.2.3.4:587. Is it possible to do in windows?